# My program keeps getting an error "division by zero"

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, eval

This program is designed to count an unspecified amount of integers,
determines how many negative and positive values have been read, 
and computes the average and total of the input values.

If the user inputs a 0, the program will end.  Every time I enter a 0, I get an error stating "division by zero".  The debugger says it is from the very last line.

I guess it has to to with the `sum / count` part.  When I use negative numbers, it says the same thing, from the same line of code. Lastly, I am unsure how to display the text "You didn't enter any number". I tried doing the if else statement, but I don't think I'm doing that correctly.

```
data = eval(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: "))
count = 0
sum = 0
negCount = 0
if data != 0:             
    while data > 0:     
        count = count + 1
        sum = sum + data 
        data = eval(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: "))       
        while data < 0:
            negCount = count + 1
            sum = sum + data
            data = eval(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: "))
            while data != 0:
                sum = sum + data              
                data = eval(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: "))
                break
            else:   
                print("You didn't enter any number")                       



print("The number of positives is", count)
print("The number of negatives is", negCount)
print("The total is", sum)
print("The average is", sum / count)
```

Comment: you are not allowed to divide by zero ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley  Is there a way for me to get the average of all the numbers without dividing?

Comment: why are u using `eval` it's bad practice and i don't see the need in your code anyway

Comment: your while loops look pretty broken also I think ... I would toss this out and start over probably ... use functions ... and print lots of debug info

Comment: I think you probably intended your whiles to be indented the same and not the way cricket_007 fixed it

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks! I am just a beginner, and I dont know how to do it another way. So, I can't really toss it. What do you mean by broken? .

Comment: @nathan.meadows I am unsure where the code you wrote fits into mine.  Are you able to take the code I have and add your to it?  Also, I tried adding your code, and it said "raw_input is not defined".

Answer (score 4):

```
output = []
while True:
    data = int(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: "))
    if data == 0:
        break
    output.append(data)

positives = len([i for i in output if i > 0])
negatives = len(output) - positives
total = sum(output)

if len(output) != 0:
    print("The number of positives is", positives)
    print("The number of negatives is", negatives)
    print("The total is", total)
    print("The average is", total / len(output))
else:
    print("You didn't enter any number")
```

Comment: You don't need the else clause.

Comment: One small performance improvement would be to save the length of the positives and the sum in temporary variables. Then `length_negatives = len(output) - length_positives - 1` (the extra 1 is for 0). Then use the stored sum variable in the total and average calculation. This avoids three unnecessary full list iterations.

Comment: @cricket_007 sadly, I do not understand all that. If you can, could you show me the correct coding to create this program?

Comment: @cricket_007 go for it

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you so much. This helps a lot. this makes sense now!

Comment: @cricket_007 is there a way show this: "You didn't enter any number" when the user enters a 0 as the first number, and not show anything else but that phrase? And I will hit the checkmark when I reach 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter 0, the `if` block is skipped (`if data != 0`). If the `if` block is skipped, `count` is 0. If `count` is 0, `sum / count` is undefined mathematically, and will raise a `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: its not undefined ... its defined as a DivideByZero error ... the mathmatical answer is undefined however (good answer +1)